# How to give the innerHTML attribute value a string of HTML code, the src attribute value of the <img> tag in the code is a relative path

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign a string of HTML code to the attribute value of innerHTML, in which I want to assign the src attribute value in the  tag to the relative path of a string of images, but the image resource cannot be obtained when the browser is executed , Later I checked the console and it showed that the src attribute value of the  tag was the image file name. (ex: 1.jpg) I tried to insert quotation marks into a relative path (ex: 11.jpg), but the result is still invalid.

**Javascript:**

```js
father.innerHTML = '<div class="mySlides fade" id="11" style="display:block;">'+
      '<a href="#"><img src="'+'./assets/teamProject/'+'11.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>'+
      '</div>'+

      '<div class="mySlides" id="1" style="display:block;">'+
        '<a href="#"><img src="./assets/teamProject/1.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>'+
      '</div>'+

      '<div class="mySlides fade" id="2" style="display:block;">'+
        '<a href="#"><img src="./assets/teamProject/2.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>'+
      '</div>';
```

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use template literals (backticks) instead, which makes variable interpolation way more readable. It also supports multiline. Also if you're only using a static string and not a variable, what's stopping you from using `<img src="./assets/teamProject/11.jpg" />` (i.e. without concatenation)?

Comment: The stuff in the screenshot does not match the code shown -> [mcve]

Comment: When you run your code, the `html` output is `<div class="mySlides fade" id="11" style="display:block;"><a href="#"><img src="./assets/teamProject/11.jpg" style="width:100%"></a></div>
 <div class="mySlides" id="1" style="display:block;"><a href="#"><img src="./assets/teamProject/1.jpg" style="width:100%"></a></div>'`. I have omitted the last `<div>` due limitations here. Please check if this is the output your expected.

Comment: Best way to debug is to run the code in `jsfiddle` or some online debugger for `html`. You can also use the `w3schools` demo pages for testing you `html` code chunks.

Comment: @Terry
I tried to add a slash at the end of the <img> tag, and then I checked the console, but the slash was not displayed at the end of the <img>.

Comment: @Andreas
I have updated the result graph.

Comment: The slash isn't required... I'm just a creature of habit from the old XHTML days

Comment: @Raky
I executed my code on jsfiddle and obtained the source code of the webpage through the result page frame. The src attribute value of the <img> tag in the code is the relative path of a series of graphic files. This is a good result for me, but the platform The upload of the image file is not accepted, so that the image cannot be viewed as well.

Comment: @yenmin, Try this Code. I have just replaced the image source as I do not have access to your path and image.
`<div class="mySlides fade" id="11" style="display:block;"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" style="width:25%"></a></div>`. Maybe the your image is not available in the path you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have integrated each of your solutions and finally solved the problem successfully.